# focusing the clicked Button in an Android Activity

Tags: android, google-tv, android-button

I have multiple buttons in an Activity. Each button opens a separate **AlertDialog**. When the app starts and i CLICK on a button through mouse, i want the clicked button to get focus .. so i can navigate through D-Pad buttons too afterwards. But it does not and , even worse, the focus sometimes is lost forever if any other item in the activity had no focus... so i cannot navigate using D-Pad buttons...

I want to clarify that this is NOT because of the **AlertDialog** that is opened after **actionItem.requestFocus()** is set .. I checked by commenting the Dialog opening code too .. but no luck

I am trying to do it as follows:

```
public void buttonClicked(View actionItem){

    //Set focus on clicked button -- but this does not work
    actionItem.requestFocus();

    switch(actionItem.getId()){
    case R.id.btnLogin:
        //Show AlertDialog 1
        break;
    case R.id.btnInfo:
        //Show AlertDialog 2
        break;
    case R.id.btnClose:
        //Show AlertDialog 3
        break;
    }
}
```

I want the clicked button to have focus before any AlertDialog opens.. so when the AlertDialog is closed, the clicked button will have focus.

this **buttonClicked** event is registered with multiple buttons .. i set it as follows:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnClose"
    style="@style/button"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/close"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:text="Exit" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnInfo"
    style="@style/button"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"                
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnClose"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/information"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:text="About" />
```

the function **buttonClicked** is called on each button'c click but that button does not get focus...

any idea y?

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of calling requestFocus() in start of the method, call it inside each case. Then you can be sure that its the right element you set in focus.

Example:

```
switch(actionItem.getId()){
case R.id.btnLogin:
actionItem.requestFocus()
    break;
}
```

That's my best guess, it works for me.

Good Luck :)